# make object available in sinatra scope

Tags: ruby, sinatra

In sinatra I have the following:

```
config = YAML.load_file('sinatra_resources/server.yml')
usernamedk = config["dkuser"]
passworddk = config["dkpass"]
passwordse = config["sepass"]
usernamese = config["seuser"]
database = config["database"]

cpooldk = OCI8::ConnectionPool.new(1, 5, 2, usernamedk, passworddk, database)
cpoolse = OCI8::ConnectionPool.new(1, 5, 2, usernamese, passwordse, database)
```

When I use any of these values in a route, it works fine. However I want to use them in a function and when I refer to these variables, etc.

As an example of my problem if I have a function

```
def getuser(lang)
 if lang == "se" then
   return usernamese
 else
   return usernamedk
end
```

and inside of a route I have 
    user = getuser(lang)

then when I try to call it with lang = "se" I get that the variable usernamese is undefined..
the same thing applies to all the variables above which I want to use in a function shared between multiple routes.

I tried the following:
    configure do

```
set :env, "local"

set :usernamedk, config["dkuser"]
set :passworddk, config["dkpass"]
set :passwordse, config["sepass"]
set :usernamese, config["seuser"]
set :database, config["database"]

set :cpooldk, OCI8::ConnectionPool.new(1, 5, 2, setting.usernamedk, setting.passworddk, setting.database)
set :cpoolse,  OCI8::ConnectionPool.new(1, 5, 2, setting.usernamese, setting.passwordse, setting.database)

end
```

but I got back the error undefined local variable or method `usernamedk' for main:Object (NameError)

Comment: The variable scope is local in your `getuser` example. The variable is not available. Can you show more code? Are you using Classic or Modular mode?

Comment: I agree with @jordelver, you should provide a bit more code, as you're talking about scope and yet it's difficult to know where the problem lies. For example, where is the function defined? Is this all in one file and you're using Sinatra's Classic mode?

Comment: It's all in one file, so I guess from here http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions.html that it would count as classic mode. I ended up just creating a bunch of global variables as that allowed me to do what I wanted - didn't think about it before, also it's quite bad form to have so many global variables.

Answer (score 2):

Why bother with all the variables when you have access to the config as a hash?

```
configure do
  # no need to set the env as local if you're trying to affect the scope

  config = YAML.load_file('sinatra_resources/server.yml')
  set :config, config

  set :cpooldk, OCI8::ConnectionPool.new(1, 5, 2, config["dkuser"], config["dkpass"], config["database"])
  set :cpoolse, OCI8::ConnectionPool.new(1, 5, 2, config["seuser"], config["sepass"], config["database"])
end

helpers do
  def getuser(lang)
    if lang == "se" then
      settings.config["seuser"] # no need for the explicit returns in Ruby
    else
      settings.config["dkuser"]
    end
  end
end

get "/some-route" do
  get_user("se")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have only local scope for your vars, they are not instance vars. You could use them as instance variables by prefixing the `@` such as `@ usernamedk` or you could use all these vars as settings (cf. https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra#configuration):

```
configure do
  set :usernamedk = config["dkuser"]
  set :passworddk = config["dkpass"]
  set :passwordse = config["sepass"]
  set :usernamese = config["seuser"]
  set :database = config["database"]
end

def getuser(lang)
  if lang == "se" then
    return settings.usernamese
  else
    return settings.usernamedk
end
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I guess from the documentation it should be set :usernamedk, config["dkuser"] but if I try something like the following: configure do
  
  set :env, "local"
  
  set :usernamedk, config["dkuser"]
  set :passworddk, config["dkpass"]
  set :passwordse, config["sepass"]
  set :usernamese, config["seuser"]
  set :database, config["database"]

  set :cpooldk, OCI8::ConnectionPool.new(1, 5, 2, setting.usernamedk, setting.passworddk, setting.database)


end
or variations I get undefined local variable or method `usernamedk' for main:Object